# Medical Equivalent of Disbarred

Tags: single-word-requests, synonyms, medical

If a doctor loses his license to practice is there an equivalent word to disbarred?

For example:

> That lawyer was disbarred
>   The doctor was (medically disbarred).

Comment: Doctors don't have a bar to be dismissed from. In the US the doctor's license to practise is revoked. In the UK I believe the doctor is "struck off the register"

Comment: @StoneyB: Indeed. But doctors being *struck off* is something of a hypothetical situation in the UK. The BMA is an incredibly powerful "behind-the-scenes" organisation, and they virtually *never* let one of their own be publically called to account. Even today, their chief negotiator admits to being taken aback when he went into the first "negotiating rounds" with Gordon Brown a few years back. Instead of negotiating at all, Brown just conceded all of their insanely unjustified demands (that they'd expected to be negotiated down from).

Comment: @FumbleFingers It's true in practically all professions everywhere. The Pope is currently making headlines for actually *defrocking!!* pederastic priests.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Is it not the GMC who do the striking-off? I can think of two doctors off the top of my head who have been struck off - Harold Shipman and Andrew Wakefield.

Comment: It appears that "disbarred" is chiefly BrE/Australia. I admire phenry's find, but it is not common at all.

Comment: @WS2: You're quite right - GMC, not BMA. But they didn't strike Shipman off until after he'd been found guilty of deliberately killing *at least* 15 patients (possibly up to 250). And they took over 6 years to strike Wakefield after the newspapers had exposed the whole sorry affair (he prolly had no interest in practising, since the big money was in his fraudulent patents etc.) As Wikipedia points out, *Shipman is the only British doctor who has been **found** guilty of murdering his patients.* But I doubt he's the only one who ***is*** (or ***was***) guilty. They're a closed shop, imho.

Comment: @StoneyB They probably didn’t look too hot in a frock in the first place.

Comment: @StoneyB What is the word used for defrocking those clergymen and women of religions where they do not wear cassocks? We recently had the case, in Britain, of the Rev'd Flowers, a Methodist minister  who was Chairman of a bank which he had milked for his own purposes, among other things, to fund an extremely colourful lifestyle. Are they detrousered?

Comment: @WS2 Hmm ... I don't know about Methodists and Presbyterians. About all you can do with congregationalist ministers is fire them--no human agency can withdraw the gift of the Holy Spirit. (You can excommunicate or disfellowship anybody, of course, not just ministers.) But  I don't know how the non-Catholic hierarchies work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Medical doctors can have their license to practice medicine revoked. I see the word "[delicensed](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22delicensed+doctor%22)" being used here and there, although, interestingly, "[disbarred](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22disbarred+doctor%22)" seems to be more popular:

> [Disbarred L.I. Doctor Is Charged in Firebombing](http://www.nytimes.com/2001/03/27/nyregion/disbarred-li-doctor-is-charged-in-firebombing.html)

> [Disbarred Doctor Loses His Appeal In Ontario Court](http://news.google.com/newspapers?nid=2194&dat=19370630&id=f-8uAAAAIBAJ&sjid=5NsFAAAAIBAJ&pg=3361,3587071)

> He apparently did not fight [disbarment](http://www.cnn.com/2010/HEALTH/05/24/autism.vaccine.doctor.banned/), the council said.

Comment: I think what we have here is a reversion (by folk-etymology, to be sure, which for once gets it right!) of *disbar* from its new sense (which I suspect began as a learned pun) to its origin as just a Latinate variant of *debar*.

Answer (score 6):

The equivalent of

> That lawyer was disbarred.

for doctors would be

> The doctor's license was revoked.

Perhaps you can say:

> The doctor was delicensed.

But that seems much more awkward.

Comment: And priests are "defrocked".

Comment: And bad geese are *deflocked*.

Comment: Bad citizens are *disarmed*.

Answer (score 4):

**Struck off** has been a long been used, as in "struck off the (medical) register".

Unregistered is also sometimes used, but probably the better word is *deregistered*.

Comment: I don't know about elsewhere, but "struck off (the (medical) register)" is the phrase routinely used in news reports in the UK.

Comment: I think that doctors do actually require a practice licence in the UK, but it's not something the general public ever hear of, so the phrase about licences which several correspondents reply as the ordinary and obvious one, is unknown in the UK.

Comment: FWIW, I have never heard this term in the US.

Answer (score 1):

The US Department of Justice (in 2013) uses the word **disbarred** for expelled from the Bar. **[disbarred](http://www.justice.gov/eoir/discipline.htm)**.

> These practitioners were expelled from practice prior to January 13, 2012. The term expelled has been replaced by the term disbarred, which has the same meaning and effect. - justice.gov.

Physicians simply say, *he/she lost his/her license*, or, more formally, *his license was revoked.*

Disbarred refers to the Bar Association, *an organization of lawyers established to promote professional competence, enforce standards of ethical conduct, and encourage a spirit of public service among members of the legal profession.*

In Medicine, various *Boards* and one Association function in that way. It is common to say a doctor was *unboarded* or *lost his Board certification*, but it is not the equivalent of losing one's license, which is worse. An unboarded doctor can still practice medicine; an unlicensed one can not.

Edited to correct an error. My apologies to all.

Answer (score 0):

In the medical community, you can also be **stripped of your license.**